# Text cut off in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, wordpress-theming, rendering

When viewing my site in IE, the site description looks as if the bottom of the letters are cut off. Of course, everything is fine and looks nice in Safari/Firefox/Chrome, but IE is killing me. It has been made on the WordPress Twenty Ten theme.

I adjusted the margins and padding with no luck. It seems that reducing the font size helps, but it can't be much smaller or it will be unreadable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Alex

Here is the page rendered in Safari and IE side by side: http://screencast.com/t/b4YnDKANsg91

Here is the header code:

```
/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#header {
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#site-title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    width: 300px;
}
#site-title a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#site-description {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
        color: #006400;
        font-size: 23px;
    font-style: regular;
    margin: 45px 0 10px 0;
    width: 610px;
}

/* This is the custom header image */
#branding img {
    border:none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

/* This is the search form in the header */
#searchform {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
        z-index: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain without seeing the full CSS, but I suspect a overflow:visible would solve this. Another selector may be setting it to clipped or hidden... If that doesn't work, try setting the height to em units instead of pixels (2em, for example).

Comment: Sdcoder, thank you for responding! Worked like a charm. I wish there was a character beyond an exclamation point, it doesn't quite do justice in this case!

Comment: Seconded, if an answer helps you, it is only good manners to accept an answer.